# Are WCF host programs opening a second thread for the service?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, blocking

I've been trying to learn about WCF services and hosts.  I made a simple host program to host my simple service.  It works fine, but I don't understand how the host program can continue completing unrelated tasks after opening the service.  Does the service run on a separate thread that opens behind the scenes?  Or when my client calls the service, does that pause the host program?  I don't see that documented anywhere.

```
   namespace MyHostProgram
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServices.Service1));
                host.Open();

                while (true)
                {
                   Console.Writeline("Doing other tasks in host program");
                }

                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that I am not asking if adding another thread will speed things up like [WCF Service and Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969324/wcf-service-and-threading), I'm asking  what the default behavior is.

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF Service and Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969324/wcf-service-and-threading)

Comment: @Amy that question is asking if he can improve his program by adding an additional thread.

Comment: At no point did that question ask that.

Comment: @Amy so what is he asking with "How can I use multithreading in WCF to speed things up ?"  still not sure how that is the same question as mine

Comment: @MikeD reading comprehension is hard.

Comment: haha some of you computer people are so weird. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the Open function of the ServiceHost class, it creates and opens the listener for the service on the configured endpoints. It does this asynchronously and the control is given back to the calling thread.

So the answers to your questions are:

> Does the service run on a separate thread that opens behind the scenes?

Yes

> when my client calls the service, does that pause the host program?

No

Answer (score -1):

All that means is Open() spawns up a new thread that contains the transport receive-loop or registers for asynchronous callbacks (depending on the binding).

You may consider reading on multi-threading and asynchronous programming to better grasp this.

Hope this helps!