# How to implement my WCF service to achive multi thread function

Tags: multithreading, wcf

I am developing one client-server system, the architecture is as below:
[system architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qda7i.png)

There are multi clients which will send different kinds of request to the Server by calling the WCF service API provided. Once the request received(one of the WCF service API be called), the WCF API will pack it into another message object then send to the main thread by the queue to proceed. After the message been proceed, response will be given.

My problems are:

1. How to pass the Queue which is instanced in the main thread to the WCF service before the service started?
2. How to start the WCF service?
3. Is there any other better way to implement my original idea?

The code of WCF service are:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWcfService
{
    [OperationContract]

    int OpenConnection(string clientId);

    bool CloseConnection(string clientId, int connectionId);

    int AllocateResource(string connectionId, int resourceType);

    int ReleaseResource(string connectionId, int resourceId);        
}

public class WcfService : IWcfService
{
    Queue MainQueue;

    public WcfService(Queue mainQueue)
    {
        this.MainQueue = mainQueue;
    }

    public int OpenConnection(string clientId)
    {
        OpenConnection req = new OpenConnection(clientId);
        MainQueue.Enqueue(req);//send request to main thread
        int connectionId = req.WaitforResponse();//wait for response            
        return connectionId;
    }

    public bool CloseConnection(string clientId, int connectionId)
    {
        CloseConnection req = new CloseConnection(clientId, connectionId);
        MainQueue.Enqueue(req);//send request to main thread
        bool succeed = req.WaitforResponse();//wait for response            
        return succeed;
    }

    public int AllocateResource(string connectionId, int resourceType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int ReleaseResource(string connectionId, int resourceId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The message class are:

public class OpenConnection : Message
{
public string ClientId;

```
    public OpenConnection(string clientId)
    {
        this.ClientId = clientId;
        this.MsgQueue = new Queue();//create queue to receive message from the main thread
    }

    public int WaitforResponse()
    {
        int connectionId = -1;
        while (true)
        {
            if (MsgQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                connectionId = (int)MsgQueue.Dequeue();
                break;
            }
        }

        return connectionId;
    }

    public void SendResponse(int connectionId)//this function will be called by main thread
    {
        MsgQueue.Enqueue(connectionId);
    }
}

public class CloseConnection : Message
{
    public string ClientId;
    public int ConnectionId;

    public CloseConnection(string clientId, int connectionId)
    {
        ClientId = clientId;
        ConnectionId = connectionId;
        this.MsgQueue = new Queue();//create queue to receive message from the main thread
    }

    public bool WaitforResponse()
    {
        bool result = false;
        while (true)
        {
            if (MsgQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                result = (bool)MsgQueue.Dequeue();
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void SendResponse(bool succeed)//this function will be called by main thread
    {
        MsgQueue.Enqueue(succeed);
    }
}
```

the main program is:

static void Main(string[] args)
{
Queue MainQueue = new Queue();//creat queue for communication between WCF service and main thread

```
        WcfService.WcfService wcf = new WcfService.WcfService(MainQueue);

        System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost host = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(wcf);

        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("WCF Service Started...");
        
        while(true)
        {
            if (MainQueue.Count > 0)//proceed message received from the wcf APIs
            {
                Message.Message msg = (Message.Message)MainQueue.Dequeue();
                Type msgType = msg.GetType();
                if (msgType == typeof(OpenConnection))
                {
                    OpenConnection newMsg = (OpenConnection)msg;
                    newMsg.SendResponse(12345);
                }
                else if (msgType == typeof(CloseConnection))
                {
                    CloseConnection newMsg = (CloseConnection)msg;
                    newMsg.SendResponse(true);
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass the Queue which is instanced in the main thread to the WCF
> service before the service started?

Queued transport in WCF uses MSMQ for queued communication. It comes with Windows as an optional component and runs as an NT service. The MSMQ queue manager implements a reliable message transfer protocol that captures transport messages in the transport queue and delivery messages in the target queue. These two links lead to [detailed introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/msmq/ms711472(v=vs.85)) and [installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/installing-message-queuing-msmq).

> How to start the WCF service?

In wcf, services need to be hosted. It cannot operate independently and needs to be hosted in program. There are several ways: Self-Host in a Managed Application, Managed Windows Services, IIS and Windows Process Activation Service. They have their own application, you can take a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/hosting-services).

Besides, you can see [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969324/wcf-service-and-threading) for other ideas about multithreading. Hope it helps.